# how to find max from lists and square it ,finally take mod

Tags: python, typeerror

There is an error when I execute This code-
 **TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

How would I fix it? (Python 3)

```
t,n=input().split()  #t refers to number of lists
l=[0]*7 #initialized list to 0 as maximum 7 elements are possible in list
s=0
for i in range(0,int(t)):
    l[i]=list(map(int,input().split()))  #take inputs for t list
for j in l:    #to find max in each list
    s=s+(max(j)*max(j))
print(s%n) 


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "solution.py", line 7, in 
s=s+(max(j)*max(j))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable


 inputs:
 3 1000
 2 5 4
 3 7 8 9
 5 5 7 8 9 10

 output:
 206
```

Comment: Please edit the full text of the error, including the traceback, into your question.

Comment: bar my last comment. traceback please. And having meaningful names for your variables would help...

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output of the above code?

Comment: @arsho have a look at the updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static declaration of `l` was creating the problems. I have made it dynamic.

Modified code:

```
t,n=list(map(int, input().split()))  #t refers to number of lists
l=[] #initialized list to 0 as maximum 7 elements are possible in list
s=0
for i in range(t):
    l.append(list(map(int,input().split())))  #take inputs for t list
for j in l:    #to find max in each list
    s=s+(max(j)*max(j))
print(s%n)
```

Sample Input:

```
3 1000
2 5 4
3 7 8 9
5 5 7 8 9 10
```

Sample Output:

```
206
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

max is a function that receive a list as parameter once you wrote "for j in l" you are pointing to a integer , therefor max(int) show you the given Error.